# Jquery: How to reorder DIVs after removing a single Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an application in which contains a few DIVs having IDs like **a1,a2,a3** etc.
There is option of navigation DIVs by hitting *next* and *previous* button which brings one Div on screen at a time. **strong text** There are two more actions: **Add** and **Remove**. Add adds a Div with ID greated than last ID, for instance if last DIV id was **a3** then Add brings **a4**.

The real issue is removing current DIV. If the user is on Div **a2** and hits **Remove** option then it deletes the current Div by using `.remove()` method of jQuery

Now navigation breaks because it is sequential. It tries to find Div **a2** but does not find. What I think that Ids of all remaining DIVs should be renamed. Since there is no **a2** so **a3** should become a2 and so on. How can I do that? Code doing different tasks is given below:

```
function removeQuestion()
{
    $("#_a"+answerIndex).remove();
    if(answerIndex > 1)
    {
        if ($("#_a"+(++answerIndex)).length > 0)
        {
            $("#_a"+answerIndex).appendTo("#answerPanel");
        }
        else if($("#_a"+(--answerIndex)).length)
        {
            $("#_a"+answerIndex).appendTo("#answerPanel");
        }
        totalOptions--;
    }
}


function addQuestion()
{
    var newId = 0;
    totalOptions++;
    var d = 1;
    newId = totalOptions;
    var _elemnew = '_a'+newId;
    $("#_a"+d).clone().attr('id', '_a'+(newId) ).appendTo("#answers_cache");
    var h = '<input onclick="openNote()" id="_note'+newId+'" type="button" value=" xx" />';
    $("#"+_elemnew+" .explain").html(h)
    $("#"+_elemnew+" ._baab").attr("id","_baab"+newId);
    $("#"+_elemnew+" ._fx").attr("id","_fasal"+newId);
    $("#"+_elemnew+" .topic_x").attr("id","_t"+newId);
    $("#"+_elemnew+" .topic_x").attr("name","_t"+newId);
    $("#"+_elemnew+" .answerbox").attr("id","_ans"+newId);
    $("#"+_elemnew+" .block").attr("onclick","openFullScreen('_ans"+newId+"')");

    $('.tree').click( function() 
      {
        toggleTree();
      }
    );
      $('.popclose').click( function() 
      {
        unloadPopupBox();
      }
    );
}

function next()
{
    console.log("Next ->");
    if(answerIndex < totalOptions)
    {
        answerIndex++;
        console.log(answerIndex);
        setInitialAnswerPanel();
    }
}
function previous()
{
    console.log("Next <-");
    if(answerIndex > 1)
    {
        answerIndex--;
        console.log(answerIndex);
        setInitialAnswerPanel();
    }
}
```

Html of Composite DIV is given below:

```
<div class="answers" id="_a1" index="1">
                <input placeholder="dd" id="_t1" type="text" name="_t1" class="urduinput topic_masla" value="" />
                <img class="tree" onclick="" src="tree.png" border="0" />
                <label class="redlabel">
                   xx                 :
                </label>
                <label id="_baab1" class="baabfasal _baab">
                </label>
                <label  class="redlabel">
                    xx                     :
                </label>
                <label id="_fasal1" class="baabfasal _fasal">
                </label>
                <a title=" ddd" class="block" href="#" onclick="openFullScreen('_ans1')">
                    <img src="fullscreen.png" border="0" />
                </a>
                <textarea id="_ans1" class="answerbox" cols="40"   rows="15"></textarea>
                <span class="explain">
                    <input onclick="openNote()" id="_note1" type="button" value=" xx" />
                </span>
                <span style="float:left;padding-top:5%">
                    <a href="#" onclick="addQuestion()">plus</a> | <a onclick="removeQuestion()" href="#">minus</a>  
                </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var originalSet = $('.answers');
var container = originalSet.up() ;
var byId = function(a, b){
    return $(a).attr('id') > $(b).attr('id') ? 1 : -1;
}
originalSet
    .order(byId)
    .each(function rearrangeIds(position){
          $(this).attr({
              'index': poition,
              'id': '_a'+position
          });
    }).appendTo(container)
```

Comment: what is Original Set here?

Comment: originalSet would be a select of all the DIVs involved in the rearrangement of IDs

Comment: Will it reorder Ids of all child DIVs too?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep currently opened page instead of the index and search for previous and next pages using `prev()` and `next()` jQuery tree traversal methods?

Answer (score 0):

Select all div elements containing questions, preferable with a css class selector, use the each method, and assign new ids to them:

```
$('.questionDiv').each(function(index) { $(this).attr('id', 'a' + (index + 1)); })
```

That should be enough.